# How to choose the normal for collision?

Tags: collision-resolution, physics-engine, normals, rigid-body-dynamics

Here two objects collide and I use impulse to calculate the velocity after the collision.
But because there are two objects, there are two normals. Calculating impulse only requires one normal.

My question is: How to choose the normal of collision?

[image]

```c
const VECTOR3<float> vCollisionPoint1 = (r2.vPoint + r2.vPoint2) / 2;
const VECTOR3<float> vCollisionPoint2 = (r2.vPoint + r2.vPoint2) / 2;
//r2 is the “line” resulting from the collision of two triangles
const VECTOR3<float> vConstraintNormal = Dynamics::Constraint::ChooseConstraintNormal(pMesh1->Triangle[i]->CalcuPointNextFrameVelocity(vCollisionPoint1),vTransformedNormal1,pMesh2->Triangle[j]->CalcuPointNextFrameVelocity(vCollisionPoint2), vTransformedNormal2);

template<typename T>
inline VECTOR3<T> ChooseConstraintNormal(const VECTOR3<T>& vVelocity1, const VECTOR3<T>& vNormal1, const VECTOR3<T>& vVelocity2, const VECTOR3<T>& vNormal2)
{
    // vVelocity1, vVelocity2 are the point velocity of the collision point
    if (dot(vVelocity1 - vVelocity2, vNormal1) > dot(vVelocity2 - vVelocity1, vNormal2))
        return vNormal1;
    else
        return vNormal2;
}
// My idea for choosing a normal is: the one that can separate the two objects as quickly as possible
```

However, my code only feels good part of the time, and has a "panning" effect part of the time because the code selects `vNormal1`.

Is there a better way of choosing which normal to apply?

Comment: My physics knowledge is quite rusty, but from the picture I think `normal2` should be the collision normal. Did you try using that at least to test the results?

Comment: @TomTsagkatos  The question is "How to use an algorithm to get it?" The algorithm "ChooseConstraintNormal" I wrote myself is not good. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: How are you choosing the two normals to pass to this function in the first place?

Comment: @DMGregory Both normals are calculated through collision. To make the collision more accurate, I use mesh triangle collision detection. So these two normals are the normals of the triangle.

Comment: Which triangles? Can you show the collision detection method that calls this?

Comment: @DMGregory This is the triangle that makes up the box. Code logic: `Loop all triangles of MESH1 -> Loop all triangles of MESH2 -> Intersection detection -> (True?) Call "ChooseConstraintNormal" -> Loop` _I modified the code in the post and added the calling process_